# Does ConnectSDK require both a tv and mobile app?

Tags: mobile

I am currently investigating the use of the [ConnectSDK](http://connectsdk.com/) by LG. While reading through their documentation, I noticed there was no clear mention of wether there should be both a TV application and mobile application, or only a mobile application.

The 'beaming' process, specifically, looks to work without having to create the 'receiving end' (SmartTV, ChromeCast, etc). It looks to be similar to the casting provided by Google Cast. Sadly, there don't seem to be any clear confirmations this is the case.

Does ConnectSDK require both a tv and mobile application to work?

*Note that I couldn't find any relevant tags.